# Does storing a car battery on its side damage it?

Tags: battery, storage, lead-acid

I just bought a new battery yesterday that I'm planning to install this weekend. I wasn't thinking and I just plunked it in my car on its side so it wouldn't tip. But then I just this remembered this morning that it contains liquid.

I went it and set it upright just now. It's a sealed, maintenance-free battery. There's no moisture on the carpet or the battery.  Can setting it horizontally cause damage to the battery or is upright storage just a safety precaution?

Comment: You'll know because they'll be a big gouged hole in your carpet.

Comment: Does it have a big disclaimer "IMPORTANT: keep upright" sign on it? Or are you in a country that doesn't have Health and Safety laws? If no sign, it'll be fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The major fear of putting a lead-acid battery on its side is it spilling sulfuric acid onto wherever it might end up. It won't hurt the battery itself, other than if it loses acid. If you are sure no acid has leaked, then it's probably a case of "no harm; no foul" and you got lucky. The meaning of "sealed" is generally stating you don't open them up to check the acid level. They still have vents which allow hydrogen gas to escape as the battery is being charged. Acid can still escape from the vent if the battery is put into a position where the acid can escape through the vent.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the battery type what bad can happen, but generally that doesn't include harm to the battery -- it includes danger of acid leaks.

Sealed, maintenance-free doesn't mean anything. It just means you can't add water (or acid -- but usually you don't have to add acid, just deionized water). But there are many types of battery where you can't add water.

Permanently sealed liquid acid batteries with no caps, you can't add water.

Gel batteries, you can't add water.

AGM batteries, you can't add water.

Note that every single one of these battery types has to have some mechanism of venting hydrogen gases. So they aren't truly sealed, just they have a valve which attempts to keep acid in but let hydrogen gas out. I wouldn't trust such a valve to keep liquid acid fully in if the battery is inverted.

The difference between these batteries is:

- In permanently sealed liquid acid batteries, the acid is liquid. It will flow out when inverted.
- In gel batteries, the acid is gel. It won't flow at all. You can invert the battery and it stays as gel. But charging when inverted, it's possible some of that gel is pushed out if hydrogen gas is created and builds up pressure.
- In AGM batteries, the (liquid) acid is absorbed in a glass mat. It will stay absorbed, but again if you recharge when inverted, and hydrogen gas builds up, it's possible you will get some small amount of acid leakage.

Usually gel batteries aren't used on cars. So it's usually a choice between liquid acid and AGM.

If your battery is liquid acid type, even if sealed and maintenance-free, keep it upright all of the time. Don't put it on its side or you may get leaked acid.

AGM, you can perfectly well put these on the side. Usually charging when completely inverted though isn't permitted.

---

If you got acid leaks, neutralize it with sodium bicarbonate or sodium carbonate (baking soda / soda). It may be useful to wash the area where the battery was carefully with a solution of soda in water even if you don't see any leaked acid.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.  I don't see any vents on this battery, but I also don't see any wording on the label like "AGM" or "SLA" and there are lots of warnings about acid, so I assume it's a regular lead-acid battery.  But again, there is no moisture anywhere.

Comment: If there's no unpainted aluminum there, you should probably still wash the area with potential acid leaks using sodium (bi)carbonate (soda) solution in water. Unpainted aluminum though can be damaged by soda, so then you may need to be more careful such as using only water and using gloves just in case there's still acid. Then dry it with paper towels. Sulphuric acid is pretty strong acid so you should still treat a potential leak as a leak.

Comment: As mentioned, agm batteries like Optima and a few other less well known are popular for off road where the battery can be mounted upside down or sideways. Completely sealed. All other car batteries, whether sealed maintenance free with less acid and/or gel type assume their batteries are mounted upright unless specifically stating they can be mounted other than right side up. Maintenance free batteries have much less battery acid as battery technology improved but will seep out eventually if mounted on its side. I have an agm battery on its side; two years with zero hints of acid leakage.